# Force first instance with compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, icc

We have made a primary storage heap memory manager that overrides the `new()` and `delete()` operators, there is a problem however since we need to initiate the memory manager *before* any other memory allocations happends - if we don't do this then the process will contain some unmanaged memory. The solution so far is to initiate the memory manager in the same file that has the `main()` function, like so:

```
/*!
\brief Start the memory manager. 
\note It's important that this is causing the very first call to the overridden new() operator.
*/
CMemoryManager *g_memoryManager = CMemoryManager::Instance();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Code...
}
```

This works but is not optimal since we need it in every executable (like every unit test) since the memory manager is such a cross-cutting concern type of functionality. What would be optimal for us was a putting the memory manager initiation in a single library and making sure that that library is executed first - thereby we don't have to add the initiation to every executable. Is there a way of doing this with G++, VC++, and the ICC compilers?

```
/**
 * \defgroup MemoryManagerMutexes Uniform mutex definitions for use with the memory manager
 */
/*@{*/
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#define MM_INIT_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) InitializeCriticalSection(&arg1);
#define MM_DELETE_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) DeleteCriticalSection(&arg1);
#define MM_ENTER_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) EnterCriticalSection(&arg1);
#define MM_LEAVE_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) LeaveCriticalSection(&arg1);
#define MM_CRITICAL_SECTION_OBJECT(arg1) CRITICAL_SECTION arg1;
#else
#ifdef HAVE_PTHREAD_H
#define MM_INIT_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) pthread_mutex_init(&arg1, NULL);
#define MM_DELETE_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) pthread_mutex_destroy(&arg1);
#define MM_ENTER_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) pthread_mutex_lock(&arg1);
#define MM_LEAVE_CRITICAL_SECTION(arg1) pthread_mutex_unlock(&arg1);
#define MM_CRITICAL_SECTION_OBJECT(arg1) pthread_mutex_t arg1;
#else
#error Neither Windows nor POSIX mutex libraries were found and no fallback
#endif
#endif
/*@}*/

/*!
\brief Get the instance of the memory manager
\details Class uses a Singleton software design pattern
\returns The instance of the memory manager
*/
CMemoryManager *CMemoryManager::Instance()
{
    if (!instance)
    { 
        MM_INIT_CRITICAL_SECTION(mutex)
        instance = new CMemoryManager();
    }

    return instance;
}

// Non-TLS new() implementation
void *operator new(size_t size) 
{
    MM_ENTER_CRITICAL_SECTION(CMemoryManager::mutex)
    void *ret = CMemoryManager::Instance()->Malloc(size);
    MM_LEAVE_CRITICAL_SECTION(CMemoryManager::mutex)
return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "instantiate" instead of "initiate" - if so you should edit so the title draws people in accurately.

Comment: I hope you have not overloaded the global new/delete

Comment: Can you just initialise the manager if not already initialised inside your `new`?

Comment: @DieterLücking Hi Dieter. We have overridden the `new()` & `delete()` and it works just fine. Is there a better way of doing it that you know of?

Comment: @AlanStokes The problem with that is that the memory manager on non-TLS systems has a mutex that unfortunately needs to be initialized *before* the `new` and `delete` methods are called for the first time.

Comment: @Inge iirc C++11 has a mutex that can be statically initialised, which might just help.

Comment: This might help: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/tbb_userguide/Automically_Replacing_malloc.htm

Comment: @AlanStokes Thanks, Alan, but our OS portable code need to support pthreads and Windows mutexes too.

Comment: @AlanStokes See my update where I added an example of the mutex initiation.

Comment: A nifty counter might do it: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter

Comment: Maybe if you override the global `operator new` and check whether the pointer is initialized there.

Comment: @DieterLücking That might work if the counter is an atomic variable - I'll look more into this, thanks.

Comment: There are possible non-portable solutions - e.g. `pragma init_seg` for VC, `init_priority` for gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Change your instance routine in the header

```
static Instance(bool first=false);
```

In the definition

```
CMemoryManager *CMemoryManager::Instance(bool first)
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        if (first)
       { 
            MM_INIT_CRITICAL_SECTION(mutex)
            instance = new CMemoryManager();
       }
       else
       {
           do {
               sleep(0);
           } while (!instance);
       }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

You will need a sleep routine of some sort.
In main

```
CMemoryManager *g_memoryManager = CMemoryManager::Instance(true);
```

Comment: I believe this could cause some concurrency issues because `instance` and `first` are not atomic variables. If they were a atomic operator variables however then this may work, I don't see the need for `first`  though.